# v4l2loopback Devices Not Showing Up In Linphone 'webcam list'

Tags: v4l

**My setup:**

- Raspberry Pi 3 (armhf)
- Raspbian Jessie (basically Debian)
- Kernel 4.4.13-v7+

I'm not using the Raspberry Pi for anything other than convenience of a testing platform. The hardware could be anything. The operating system doesn't really matter to me either.

---

**My issue:**

I want to register a v4l2loopback video device (virtual video device) with linphone. Ultimately, ffmpeg will write to this video device, but I'm just trying to get the linphone portion working first.

Linphone is not recognizing the v4l2loopback devices as video devices when I run the command

```
webcam list
```

in the linphone CLI. The only output from that command is

> 0: StaticImage: Static picture

which is the normal output. I'm expecting to see some additional lines there recognizing my v4l2loopback devices.

---

**What I've tried:**

- Messing with some options in /root/.linphonerc, but none of the changes that I made fixed the issue. In fact, some of them wouldn't even persist when I restarted the system to apply them.
- Adding `bcm2835-v4l2` to /etc/modules
- Running command:

  ```
  export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libv4l/v4l1compat.so`
  ```
- Changing permissions of v4l2 devices: `chmod 777 /dev/video*

---

**Linphone Installation:**

Installing dependencies:

```
apt-get install cmake automake autoconf libtool intltool yasm libasound2-dev libpulse-dev libv4l-dev nasm git libglew-dev
```

Source code:

```
git clone git://git.linphone.org/linphone-desktop.git --recursive
```

Build options:

```
./prepare.py no-ui -DENABLE_OPENH264=ON -DENABLE_WEBRTC_AEC=OFF -DENABLE_UNIT_TESTS=OFF -DENABLE_MKV=OFF -DENABLE_FFMPEG=ON -DENABLE_CXX_WRAPPER=OFF -DENABLE_NON_FREE_CODECS=ON -DENABLE_VCARD=OFF -DENABLE_BV16=OFF -DENABLE_V4L=ON
```

Running the executable:

```
./linphone-desktop/OUTPUT/no-ui/bin/linphonec -C
```

---

**V4L2Loopback Installation**

Source code:

```
git clone https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback.git
```

Build:

```
make && make install
```

Add video devices:

```
modprobe v4l2loopback devices=3
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if the answer is not relevant anymore. When loading the v4l2loopback module the option `exclusive_caps` shoud be set. And the stream from ffmpeg must be fed to `/dev/video0` before linphone starts

https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/blob/master/README.md

Regards